# How can I call a derived const function defined in base class while I have a same named one in sub class?

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

The code looks like this.

Why p1->display() causes a build error?

How can I call `display() const` by a Derived ptr?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base
{
    public:
        virtual void display() const
        {
            std::cout << "Base display const!" << std::endl;
        }
        virtual ~Base(){}
};

class Derive: public Base
{
    public:
        virtual void display()
        {
            std::cout << "Derive display!"<< std::endl;
        }
        virtual ~Derive(){}
};

int main()
{
    const Base *pb1 = new Derive();
    pb1->display(); // Base display const!
    Base *pb2 = new Derive();
    pb2->display(); // Base display const!
    const Derive *p1 = new Derive();
    //p1->display(); // Build Error
    Derive *p2 = new Derive();
    p2->display();  // Derive display!
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `virtual void display()` -> `virtual void display() const` in `Derive`.

Comment: ... or `const Derive* p1 = new Derive();` -> `Derive* p1 = new Derive();`

Answer (score 2):

The non-`const` `display()` in `Derive` is hiding the `const` `display()` in `Base`.

Add this in `Derive` to bring it in:

```
using Base::display;
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/cjahee)

Note that you now have two `virtual` overloads that may be overridden separately.

```
class Last : public Derive {
public:
    void display() override { std::cout << "non-const overridden\n"; }
    void display() const override { std::cout << "const overridden\n"; }
};

int main() {
    Derive* l1 = new Last;
    l1->display();                 // prints non-const overridden
    const Derive* l2 = new Last;   // prints const overridden
    l2->display();
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Can you explain why and how The non-const display() in Derive is hiding the const display() in Base.

Comment: I think I've understood.

Comment: @Yuan You're welcome! The name hiding occurs when you define a function in one scope (`Derive`) that is also defined in an outer scope (`Base`). By doing `using Base::display` you bring the outer scope's all `display` declarations into the inner scope.